# Mongoose new Schema post sub array with ng-select

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, angular-ngselect

I have this Schema:

```
    const userSchema = new Schema({
        email: String,
        skills: {
            name: String,
            label: String
        }
    })
    module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users')
```

Using ng-select in HTML like this:

```
    <ng-select [items]="options" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value" 
       [addTag]="addCustomSkill" [multiple]="true" 
       placeholder="Select Skills" [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.skills"
       name="skills">
    </ng-select>
```

And I want to Post to mLab like this:

```
  registerUser() {
    this._auth.registerUser(this.registerUserData)
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res),
        err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

Console will log the email but not the skills..

and, of course, mLab will put only the email

> Update:

I managed to make it work by changing the skills to

```
skills: Array,
```

and:

```
name="skills[]"
```

But it will post without key the subarray, only the value like:

```
"skills": [
    "JAVA"
],
```

I want it to be:

```
"skills": [
    "name": "JAVA"
    "label": "JAVA"

],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a schema for your skill object also, and use it like this:

```
const skillSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    label: String
});
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    skill: skillSchema
});
```